# Insert the same fixed value into multiple rows

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, sql-insert

I've got a table with a column, lets call it `table_column` that is currently `null` for all rows of the table.  I'd like to insert the value `"test"` into that column for all rows.  Can someone give me the SQL for this?

I've tried  `INSERT INTO table (table_column) VALUES ("test");` but that only populates that last row.  How do I do all of the rows at once?

Comment: The title and the content of your post contradict. "multiple rows" vs. "all rows"

Answer (score 114, accepted):

You're looking for [UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html) not insert.

```
UPDATE mytable
SET    table_column = 'test';
```

UPDATE will change the values of existing rows (and can include a WHERE to make it only affect specific rows), whereas INSERT is adding a new row (which makes it look like it changed only the last row, but in effect is adding a new row with that value).

Comment: Found the question because I actually *do* want to insert multiple rows with all the same column values (except the autoincremented primary key, which i wouldn't provide in an insert anyway).

Comment: Use `SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;` if the `Workbench` issues any errors

Answer (score 29):

This is because in relational database terminology, what you want to do is not called "inserting", but "UPDATING" - you are updating an existing row's field from one value (NULL in your case) to "test"

```
UPDATE your_table SET table_column = "test" 
WHERE table_column = NULL
```

You don't need the second line if you want to update 100% of rows.

Comment: I gave you +1 just because you're about the only other one that posted an answer and a reason. No one on SO seems to post reasoning or references any more, they want to be first to the draw.

Comment: Ironically enough, I just gave you +1 for the comprehensive answer and especially reference link :)

Comment: @Brad To be fair, you also posted the raw answer only, initially - then you edited your post to add some explanations. When I sent my answer, yours was 30" ahead, and had already 2 upvotes... So you are right, the *first in the draw* get the upvote for that kind of question.

Comment: @ring0: You are correct, but more or less fat-fingered and pre-submitted the form. I still feel it's important to give further explanation on questions such as this. The old "teach a man to fish" adage, not "here, use this--this will do what you want". I sometimes feel people vote too quickly on the working not, not the best quality post, but not much I can do about it. I've seen posts with 10 up-votes and just working code succeed and become an answer, when one with no upvotes and a descriptive answer remains at the bottom. :shrug:

Comment: @ring0 - Yep that is true. Best strategy is to post a short (but meaningful and correct) answer straight away then perhaps edit it to add in a few "optional extra" points. Voting patterns don't favour those who compose a full answer before posting for this type of easy question.

Comment: the WHERE clause answers the title of the question. Thanks for that and +1

Answer (score 4):

To update the content of existing rows use the `UPDATE` statement:

```
UPDATE table_name SET table_column = 'test';
```

Answer (score 2):

What you're actually doing is adding rows. To update the content of existing rows use the UPDATE statement:

```
UPDATE table SET table_column = 'test';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE `table` SET table_column='test';
```

Answer (score 1):

The SQL you need is:

```
Update table set table_column = "test";
```

*The SQL you posted creates a new row rather than updating existing rows.*

Answer (score 1):

To create a new empty column and fill it with the same value (here 100) for every row (**in Toad for Oracle**):

```
ALTER TABLE my_table ADD new_column INT;
UPDATE my_table SET new_column = 100;
```