# How to update new values in a column without affecting old ones in sqlite database

Tags: python-3.x, database, sqlite

I have created a table called Employees with 3 columns namely names,exp and samples and I am trying to insert values individually as below:

```
test = Company()
test.details()

DML = '''INSERT INTO Employees (Names,Exp) VALUES(?,?)'''
data = list(zip_longest(test.names,test.exps,fillvalue= None))
self.curr.executemany(DML,data)
self.curr.execute('''UPDATE Employees SET Samples = 'sample1' ''')
self.conn.commit()
```

Company is the class created in another python file and it has a corresponding function **details()** which is being called in the current file. Names and Exp columns
have list of values stored in test.names and test.exps respectively. When executed the values are properly being inserted but the third column Samples varies for each insertion
hence I need to populate it individually. When I execute the above:

```
# In the db

 Names | Exp | Samples
  
 John  |  2  |  sample1
 Cena  |  4  |  sample1
 Tom   |  6  |  sample1
```

Since, names and exps are list I am changing the list values in the other file for each insertion and its working as expected. For the above John,Cena,Tom are first list values of test.names. Similarly, 2,4,6 are first list values of test.exps
Each time I insert the values for a particular list the sample value remains same as in:

```
# In the db First insertion

 Names | Exp | Samples
  
 John  |  2  |  sample1
 Cena  |  4  |  sample1
 Tom   |  6  |  sample1
 
# Second insertion (expected)

 Names | Exp | Samples
  
 John  |  2  |  sample1
 Cena  |  4  |  sample1
 Tom   |  6  |  sample1
 Meg   |  3  |  sample2
 Cena  |  4  |  sample2
 Renu  |  6  |  sample2
```

But each time I insert the value Names and Exp are perfect but the Samples column value gets replaced by new ones as in:

```
 Names | Exp | Samples
  
 John  |  2  |  sample2
 Cena  |  4  |  sample2
 Tom   |  6  |  sample2
 Meg   |  3  |  sample2
 Cena  |  4  |  sample2
 Renu  |  6  |  sample2
```

I also tried with **self.curr.execute('''UPDATE Employees SET Samples = 'sample1' where Samples = NULL ''')** but no luck. Is there any way I can update sample values without affecting the old values.
PS: I do not want to delete or replace the old values.

Comment: `where Samples IS NULL`. Never compare to NULL with =.

Comment: A silly mistake. Thanks it worked when corrected. Followed [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4693194/14715110) solution and ended up giving =